# How do I store a block of HTML in string variable?

Tags: javascript, string, encode

I am trying to assign a HTML block to a string variable in JavaScript. However enclosing quotation/speech marks aren't doing the trick. Is there another way to do this.

This is what I have tried:

```
var huge = '<div class="row"><div class.../div>'
```

I've realised I could put / before the quotation marks. However given the size of the block that doesn't seem like a great solution.

EDIT: Sorry, wasn't very clear. I meant that within the block of html code there are multiple sets of double quotes/single quotes which clash with the enclosing single quotes.

Comment: You can try http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: What do you mean they aren't doing the trick? Are you given an error?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. There's no jQuery involved at all, just a string that seems fine, as far as it goes. The double quotes inside the single quotes will be fine; you don't seem to have shown the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is you have a huge block of code consisting of both single quotes and double quotes, your options are to either escape it server-side first, or you'll have to manually format it.

```
var huge = "<div class=\"foo\">bar</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code in your HTML, rather than in your javascript, but hiding it with CSS. You can then either access it as a DOM element or use .html() to get it as a string.